# VS2017 Asp.net Core with Linux docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Creating a new Asp.net Core project with Linux container:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

    FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY *.sln ./
    COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj WebApplication1/
    RUN dotnet restore
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1
    RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: corewithdocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication1/Dockerfile
```

After running the application, it creates the corewithdocker:dev image, then I call `docker run -p 8888:80 corewithdocker:dev`, the container exited immediately, why? The ENTRYPOINT is `["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]`, shouldn't the container keep running? (call dotnet webapplication1.dll manually, it keeps running unless press ctrl+c).

If I call `docker run -dit -p 8888:80 corewithdocker:dev`, the container is up, but I can't access `localhost:8888`, do not know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is this line "FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base WORKDIR /app EXPOSE 80" part of your dockerfile . Either way the port 80 is not exposed in the docker image hence your image is existing when trying to bind port 8080 to internal port 80 .
add the line expose 80 to your docker file.

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Comment: Yes, the line is the part of the dockerfile, so it exports 80 port, but don't work.